# Find base entity name from jpql

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have a jpql and would like to find the alias for the base entity given in the jpql at run time. is it possible?

eg `SELECT home FROM HomeEntity home WHERE homeId IS NOT NULL;`

i would like to find out the alias, in this case "home" from the query before executing it so that I can modify the query at run time like add an `ORDER BY home.createdDate` to the jpql before it is executed.

Comment: You can always parse it with regex. The alias will always be at that position. `FROM EntityName alias WHERE ...`. This might not be true in all environments. Why don't you just save yourself the trouble and have multiple JPQL Strings?

Comment: i wanted to make a generic method so i don't have to add the entity alias myself in all the queries since it's pretty much common ('createdDate')
i was looking at parsing only to find the alias, but thought there might be a more elegant solution present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up parsing the JPQL and pulling out the base entity alias using regex. Below is the code. Feel free to use it or improve it or provide suggestions.
private String findBaseEntityAliasFromJPQL(String jpqlString) {

```
    String baseEntityAlias = null;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("SELECT.+?FROM.+?\\w+?\\s+?(\\w+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(jpqlString);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        baseEntityAlias = matcher.group(1);
    }
    Assert.hasText(baseEntityAlias, "Not able to find the base Entity Alias for the JPQL Query=" + jpqlString);
    return baseEntityAlias;
}
```